# Firebase authentication with Redux-Saga not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to create a new user using firebase auth. I am using redux-saga to make the above call.

Below is my **saga.js:**

```
import { takeLatest, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { SIGN_UP, AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, SIGN_UP_SUCCESS} from '../actions/index';
import firebase from 'firebase';


function* signUp(action){
    console.log("about to call authentication"); // This being printed
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(action.user.email, action.user.password)
            .then(function*(result){
                    console.log("success"); // Not being loged
                    yield put({SIGN_UP_SUCCESS, user: action.user});
            }).catch(function*(error){
                    console.log("failed"); //Not being loged
                    let error_message = { code: error.code, message: error.message};
                    yield put({AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, error: error_message});
            });
}

function* rootSaga(){
  yield takeLatest(SIGN_UP, signUp);
}

export  default rootSaga;
```

The code inside `then` and `catch` is not being executed, Sign Up generator function is being called. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A more `redux-saga` idiomatic way of writing the code would look like this:

```
function* signUp(action){
  try {
    const auth = firebase.auth()
    const result = yield call(
      [auth, auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword],
      action.user.email,
      action.user.password
    )

    yield put({ type: SIGN_UP_SUCCESS, user: action.user });
  } catch (error) {
    const error_message = { code: error.code, message: error.message };

    yield put({ type: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, error: error_message });
  }
}
```

Please see https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callcontext-fn-args for `call`'s documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code above is that you are passing generators as handlers of the `then` and `catch`. They should be just functions since there is no any code to iterate over them. What happens is that you get a generator iterator created.

You are of course free to use promises but I'll suggest to follow the redux-saga way and pass your `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to `yield call`.